# Link which jumps to specific method in deployed javadoc

Tags: html, javadoc

I want to generate a URL which, when opened, jumps to a specific method in the Javadoc.

I would assume that the standard Javadoc generator also adds the `id` attribute to some element containing the method. That way it would have been easy. A URL could look like `http://example.com/javadoc/some/package/MyClass#specialMethod`. Sadly I can't see the `id` attribute set anywhere in the generated Javadoc files.

Is it possible to pass arguments to the javadoc generator which would also add ids to the methods?
Or do I have to edit the source of the javadoc generator?

Another solution I thought of, was adding html to every method I'm interested in. Something like `<p id="specialMethod" style="visibility:hidden;"></p>`, but I wouldn't like to do this for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, that there is a `<a>` tag surrounding the title of the method with the `name` attribute set. `<a name="specialMethod--"></a>`.

So I just had to add the two dashes at the end of the url:

`http://example.com/javadoc/some/package/MyClass#specialMethod--`

This may not work in the future as per HTML5 the `name`attribute is obsolete on the `a` tag.